# C# console app that calls PowerShell 5.1 commands - Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-code, .net-core, powershell-core

I am writing a Windows Console app that will run as a service. The console app must be able to execute Windows PowerShell 5.1 commands. The commands that I need are not yet compatible with Powershell Core 6.0.

When I try creating a console app using **.NET Core**, it appears that I can only target **PowerShell Core** and not **Powershell 5.1.**

When I try creating the console app using **.NET Framework 4.7**, I do not see any way to include what I need for calling PowerShell at all.

I am looking for a way to use **.NET Core** to call **PowerShell 5.1** commands and module OR a way that I can use **.NET Framework 4.7** and reference assemblies for calling **Powershell 5.1 commands**.

If you can point me to any articles or have code snippets I would be greatly appreciative. - Thank you!

Comment: It's just a wall of text.. upgrade your PowerShell

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not sure what you mean. I do have the newest version of Windows Powershell 5.1 and Powershell Core 6.0.2 installed. My issue is with creating a console app that will be running as a service which will call Powershell. I need to be able to call Powershell 5.1 as the modules I use are not compatible with Powershell Core.

Comment: This guy is using .Net Core 2.0 and he can reference Powershell 5.1: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4894